# Stripping a comma in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that consists three associative arrays. I am trying to strip out the comma from the price:

```
for ($i =1 ; $i<4; $i++) {
foreach ($array[$i]['product'] as $products) {
    str_replace(',', '', $products ['price']);
}
}
```

Comment: Cool. In what way is the code you posted not doing what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: You string manipulation operates on _copies_ of the array elements...

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i =1 ; $i<4; $i++) {
  foreach ($array[$i]['product'] as $products) {
    $products ['price'] = str_replace(',', '', $products ['price']);
  }
}
```

You need to assign the value back to the array. Or:

```
for ($i =1 ; $i<4; $i++) {
  foreach ($array[$i]['product'] as $products) {
    $array [$i]['product']['price'] = str_replace(',', '', $products ['price']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I may have some other issues with my code so i need to review this more carefully. thank you!